# Python: Using continue in a try-finally statement in a loop

Tags: python, continue, try-finally

Will the following code:

```
while True:
    try:
        print("waiting for 10 seconds...")
        continue
        print("never show this")
    finally:
        time.sleep(10)
```

Always print the message "waiting for 10 seconds...", sleep for 10 seconds, and do it again? In other words, do statements in `finally` clauses run even when the loop is `continue`-ed?

Comment: @AndrewG., the point of asking the question was so that this information be more easily find-able. It took me a few minutes to come up with that example. :)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

From the [python docs](http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#finally):

When a return, break or continue statement is executed in the try suite of a try...finally statement, the finally clause is also executed ‘on the way out.’ A continue statement is illegal in the finally clause. (The reason is a problem with the current implementation — this restriction may be lifted in the future).

Comment: [As of Python 3.8](https://docs.python.org/dev/whatsnew/3.8.html#other-language-changes) continue statements are legal within the finally clause.

Answer (score 5):

The documentation uses slightly unclear language ("on the way out") to explain how this scenario plays out.  If a continue statement is executed inside of an exception clause, the code in the finally clause will be executed and then the loop will continue on to the next iteration.

Here's a very clear example that demonstrates the behavior.

Code:

```
i=0
while i<5:
    try:
        assert(i!=3) #Raises an AssertionError if i==3
        print("i={0}".format(i))
    except:
        continue
    finally:
        i+= 1; #Increment i

'''
Output:

i=0
i=1
i=2
i=4
'''
```

Comment: What exactly would be unclear in the original documentation?

Answer (score 1):

Now from the latest version of python (3.8.4) , 'continue' can be used inside 'finally' blocks.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RHf7x.png)

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.  It's always best to post code as text, not as images.  Others can then copy/paste to try it.  Highlight the code and press Ctrl+k or highlight and click the '{}' symbol in the answer box.