# While loop skips a cycle if an error is handled. How can I make it run the rest of the cycle?

Tags: python, loops, error-handling, while-loop

I'm still new to Python and I wrote some code to help me go through some online listings.

I had to get some error handling in there as when an attribute of the listing isn't found, it would crash the program.

If I try to use pass or continue I just get stuck in an infinite loop, as expected.

I feel like I've written myself into a corner and I just can't seem to find a solution. The solutions I found I could not figure out and most were for other languages.

How can I make this work so that the loop doesn't skip over all of the other attributes once an error is found?

EDIT:
I think my post was unclear on that point, my apologies. What happens is this: If the element of interest in a listing is not found, the other elements are skipped over. So if the listing has no owner name specified (the first element or attribute), the whole listing gets ignored. It continues on to the next listing. Any idea how I could fix that?

Here's the part of the code:

```
#iterate through the results according to user input earlier
i = 0
while (i < number_of_results):

    Result_page = driver.current_url
#define elements of the listing of interest
    stran = requests.get(driver.current_url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(stran.content, 'html.parser')
    ime = soup.find("dd", itemprop="name")
    ulica = soup.find("dd", itemprop="streetAddress")
    postna_stevilka = soup.find("span", itemprop="postalCode")
    kraj = soup.find("span", itemprop="addressLocality")
    tel = soup.find("dd", itemprop="telephone")
    spletna_stran = soup.find("dd", itemprop="url") 
    mobil = soup.find("a", itemprop="telephone")
    
    try:
        print(ime.text)
        c1 = sheet.cell(row=i+1, column=1)
        c1.value = ime.text
        print(ulica.text)
        c1 = sheet.cell(row=i+1, column=2)
        c1.value = ulica.text
        print(postna_stevilka.text)
        c1 = sheet.cell(row=i+1, column=3)
        c1.value = postna_stevilka.text
        print(kraj.text)
        c1 = sheet.cell(row=i+1, column=4)
        c1.value = kraj.text
        print(tel.text)
        c1 = sheet.cell(row=i+1, column=5)
        c1.value = tel.text
#print(mobil.text) does not work, cut out to prevent error
        print(spletna_stran.text)
        c1 = sheet.cell(row=i+1, column=6)
        c1.value = spletna_stran.text
        
        
#catch the error when an entry isn't there      
    except AttributeError:
        print("No such entry.")
    
       
        

    next_entry = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/main/chousingdetail/div/div[2]/div[1]/nav/div/div[2]/a[2]/i")
    next_entry.click()
    i +=1
```

Comment: i think **continue** should be after **except** and after **finally** there shod be a function which will be executed regardless of the exception https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10544928/python-using-continue-in-a-try-finally-statement-in-a-loop#:~:text=If%20a%20continue%20statement%20is,on%20to%20the%20next%20iteration.

Comment: finally block runs no matter what and in your finally block you have `continue` which doesn't let the code below it run.
so i would suggest you to move all the blocks below `continue` to finally block.
it should work

Comment: or remove `continue` from the `finally` block

Comment: @AmitKumar My original code did not have either 'continue' or the 'finally' clauses, those were my attempts to get the loop to return to the attributes and extract the other information. 
I think my post was unclear on that point, my apologies. 
What happens is this: 
If the element of interest in a listing is not found, the other elements are skipped over. So if the listing has no owner name specified (the first element or attribute), the whole listing gets ignored. It continues on to the next listing. 
Any idea how I could fix that?

Comment: @CYREX Thank you for the link to that thread! I think I was unclear on my problem, I've edited my post accordingly. My code originally did not have those clauses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you're trying to do, you should not be using `try...except` like that.

As soon as `try` block encounters an exception, it jumps into the `except` block. It will not "try" the rest of the lines. So, if you want all the elements to be checked regardless of any one of them failing, you'd need to put each one of them in separate `try...except` blocks. For example,

```
try:
    print(ime.text)
    c1 = sheet.cell(row=i+1, column=1)
    c1.value = ime.text
except:
    pass

try:
    print(ulica.text)
    c1 = sheet.cell(row=i+1, column=2)
    c1.value = ulica.text
except:
    pass
```

and so on. This way, a missing value will be handled, and the script will just move to the next element.

However, here's how I'd prefer to do it: because `bs4.BeautifulSoup.find()` returns `None` if it doesn't find anything, you could use:

```
ime = soup.find("dd", itemprop="name")
if ime:
    print(ime.text)
    c1 = sheet.cell(row=i+1, column=1)
    c1.value = ime.text
```

and so on. I'd even wrap those lines up in a function since they're almost the same for each element. (In fact, there are a few improvements I could suggest to your code, but maybe that's for another discussion; I'll stick to the question for now!)

Comment: Thank you. Ugh, the solution is so obvious now. I guess I was too focused on keeping as much of my code the way it is as possible. Your preferred way to do it looks very slick. 
For some reason I completely forgot about `if`. 
I'll try this out right now. :)

Comment: I've just used your method and it works great! I've marked this as the answer as it solves my problem. 
I'm sorry to ask this of you, but I would also be very grateful for any suggestions to my code as I'm very clumsy with Python...

Comment: @Coercer_, this is not the best forum for this, but briefly: 1) wrap up repeated steps in a function to reduce the code and make it easier to maintain; e.g., `get_item_value(col)`. 2) Where does `number_of_results` come from? Consider ending the loop when "next" can't be found; makes code more robust. 3) Looks like you want a table. A natural structure for that is a list `[row_1 ... row_n]`, where `row_i = { ime_i.attrs["itemprop"]: ime_i.text, ... etc.}`. That list can readily be exported into a CSV/spreadsheet with csv.DictWriter.

Comment: Thank you once again. The `number_of_results` comes from code before this part of the code. The user is asked for a postal code and number of listings to go through. I didn't post all of it as I thought it wise to focus on the parts giving me trouble. Then the code runs a search on the site in question.

Yeah, I'm building a table with the relevant info from the listings. I'm using openpyxl to write the info into cells and then save a workbook.

Answer (score -1):

Copy paste the last three lines inside the `finally` statement.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried it and it does work. However, it does not solve my problem with the attributes getting skipped over as soon as an attribute is not found. I've edited my post to clarify.